# Activity theme background - Memory issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

I am trying simple app where am setting the activity background in custom theme. But I observed drastic increase in memory usage (when compared without background),also memory usage still increases when I change the orientation.

How to avoid this. Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decrease the resources needed, if possible, your best option would be using a [9patch image](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html).

Other options include:

- Optimize your graphic - using something like http://trimage.org or something
- Decrease the image dpi